# jQuery Sortable Table Columns: creating extra column

Tags: jquery, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm creating a table where the columns can be sorted by dragging the column headers.
I'm using jQuery sortable for this.

Here's a jsfiddle I created as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/jAXCc/43/

It works! But when you start dragging the first column to the right a little bit, the other columns move out of the table! It's like it makes an extra column.

Anybody having a solution for this behaviour?

HTML CODE:

```
<div style='display:table;'>
    <div id="sortable" class="Row">
       <span id="col1" class="Column">Name</span>
       <span id="col2" class="Column">Age</span>
       <span id="col3" class="Column">City of Birth</span>
    </div>
    <div id="row1" class="Row">
        <span id="row1col1" class="data">Pete</span>
        <span id="row1col2" class="data">48</span>
        <span id="row1col3" class="data">New York</span>
    </div>
    <div id="row2" class="Row">
        <span id="row2col1" class="data">Sarah</span>
        <span id="row2col2" class="data">43</span>
        <span id="row2col3" class="data">Moscow</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most charming solution, but you can add this code to your CSS:

```
.ui-sortable-placeholder {

    display: none;

}
```

Comment: Gets me closer to my solution. Not the total answer, because it´s not as nice as in the demo´s, but thanks anyway. For now it will do! :-) Hoping someone else has the final touch!

Comment: I think the problem is that you're using div with table behaviour.

Comment: I think this is the best solution. It's not optimal, but the using of tables is probably not making a perfect solution possible. I'm also thinking would I really want the normal behaviour of sortable in a table. So this solution is fine for me! Thanks!